# Highchairs how to prepend HTML to legend

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts and I want to prepend some html to the legend that is automatically generated.

```
legend: {
    useHTML: true,
    labelFormatter: function(){
        return '<div>Div that I want to prepend</div>';
     }
}
```

The above code will replace the legend not append to it.

Can anybody tell me how I can prepend to the legend rather than overwrite it?

Comment: Provide some mockup, otherwise it's hard to suggest something better than Anatoli (which answers are correctly IMHO - he is answering your question). Also try out [legend.title](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.title) option. If this won't suit you, then most probably you need to disable default legend and create your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({.......});

$(chart.legend.group.div).find('span').append('<div>Div that I want to prepend</div>');
```

Comment: This code addes to every element of legend what you want. You can add for one element and to make prepend. But if you try to add before all element with class "highcharts-legend" you'll have troubles with position absolute. You will have to calculate positions like HighCharts.

Answer (score 0):

```
labelFormatter: function () {
      return this.name + '<div>Div that I want to prepend</div>';
}
```

Comment: Sorry no i want to prepend my custom html to the entire existing legend as opposed to writing a new legend from scratch.